# Name for such special functions?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given a mapping $f: X\times X \to Y$.

If $f(x_1, x_2)= f(x_2, x_1)$ for all $x_1, x_2 \in X$,  $f$ is called symmetric.

If $\{f_x(\dot\,) := f(x, \dot\,), x \in X\}$ and $\{f_x(\dot\,) := f(\dot\,,x), x \in X\}$ are the same set of mappings, what is the name of such property? What other nice properties from such property?

Thanks!

Comment: I feel this is unclear. Do you mean that interchanging $x,y$ as formal variables leaves a specific function unchanged at every point, or that the class of functions $S$ is closed under this permutation of the variables. You currently have the second writen

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want $(\forall x\ \exists y\ \forall a)\space xa=ay$ and 
$(\forall y\ \exists x\ \forall a)\space xa=ay$ ?

Comment: @StellaBiderman: The second.

Comment: Cool. My answer is now "no bloody clue". But probably not.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not. I've never heard of this specific class of functions discussed in general. What situation do you want this word for?

EDIT: The original question was (as interpreted by me) different. Preserving this answer for the comments.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my post.

Comment: Stella, this is not quite what Tim was asking (even in the original, although it was harder to see it there). His property does not guarantee that $f(x,\cdot)=f(\cdot, x)$ but more generally that for every $x$ there is some $y$ such that $f(x,\cdot)=f(\cdot, y)$.

Comment: Oh, hmmm. That's a much more general property. I doubt that there is a name for it.

Comment: @Tim: I also don't think there's a name for this.

Comment: This situation http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/88738/1005